# AWS SQS - How to check the last poll time?

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Is there an option in AWS console to view the timestamps at which polls were requested to SQS? I like to see when was the last time the queue was polled by a client.

The closest metric I can see in CloudWatch is NumberOfMessagesReceived, which is the number of messages returned by calls to the ReceiveMessage API action. But I also like to see the timestamp at which these calls were made.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a value that's exposed.

However, `NumberOfEmptyReceives` may be somewhat useful -- it's the metric of the number of times during each time interval that the queue was polled and no messages were returned because no messages were in the queue at the moment.  If it is continually 0, then either your queue is not being polled, or your workers are never idle/always busy, becauae every time they poll, there are always messages to be received.

Comment: Building on your answer, I think `NumberOfMessagesReceived` should be used with `NumberOfMessagesSent` to find out polling inactivity. For example, when the last time we see `NumberOfMessagesSent > 0` and `NumberOfMessagesReceived = 0` after that time, then we can tell that the client is not actively polling. Is my understanding correct?